# My loader for discord.js commands is not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

my command loader doesn't work.
Basically, it should load all the .js files from folder ./commands/info
What it does is, that it says its all loaded up and ready and stuff, but the bot doesn't go online on discord. I tried changing the token, remixing the project or even going through the code, but nothing did work. I am hosting it on glitch.me.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// make all the files in 'public' available
// https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static("public"));

// https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});

// listen for requests :)
const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port + "\nBot is now ready!");
});

// LOAD COMMANDS
const { Client, Collection, Attachment } = require("discord.js");
const { config } = require("dotenv");
const discord = require("discord.js");


const client = new discord.Client();

// Collections
client.commands = new Collection();
client.aliases = new Collection();

config({
    path: __dirname + "/.env"
});

// Run the command loader
["command"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  var guilds = [];
    client.guilds.cache.array().forEach( (guild) =>{
        guilds.push(guild.name);
    });

client.on('ready', () => {
  var guilds = [];
    client.guilds.cache.array().forEach( (guild) =>{
        guilds.push(guild.name);
    });

    if(guilds.length > 0){
        console.log("Servers:");
        console.log(guilds.join("\n"));
        console.log();
    }
})


    const prefix = "*";

client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    // If message.member is uncached, cache it.
    if (!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();



    // Get the command
    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    // If none is found, try to find it by alias
    if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));

    // If a command is finally found, run the command
    if (command)
        command.run(client, message, args);
});
// -----

client.login(process.env.SECRET);

})
```

any help would be greatly appriciated
**note: it doesnt say any errors, it just doesn't go online**

Comment: Might be because of: https://status.glitch.com/

Comment: Nope, my other bot with different server.js works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem.

You're putting all your code in the `client.on('ready')` function.

See that `})` after `client.login`? Put the `})` after the `guilds.push()`.

Since the client.login is in the ready event, you're trying to log in after it's ready, which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you very much! It pretty much fixed it, now I got to fix some errors with package.json. Is there any way I can +rep you or smth?

Comment: You're welcome! By marking this post as the check mark (best answer) you are +rep ing me. :)